# Updating in Entity Framework - The following objects have not been refreshed because they were not found in the store

Tags: entity-framework

I'm saving an Order object using the following code:

```
public void SaveOrder (string orderNo)
{
    using (var se = new StoreEntities)
    {
        var order = new Order { OrderNumber = orderNo }

        try
        {
            //// Update
            if (se.Orders.Any(e => e.OrderNumber == orderNo))
            {
                se.Orders.Attach(order);
                se.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(order, EntityState.Modified);
            }
            //// Create
            else
            {
                se.Orders.AddObject(order);
            }
            se.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException){
            se.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, order);
            se.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when it's a new order and I'm just inserting into the DB.
However, if I'm trying to update an existing order, I get his error:

> The following objects have not been refreshed because they were not
>   found in the store:  'EntitySet=Orders;OrderID=0'.

In the database, the Order table looks like

```
OrderID | OrderNumber
13        567-87
15        567-93
```

where OrderID is an Identity key. There are no other rows besides these two as they have been deleted.

What am I doing wrong that I can't update a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting the error because you're attaching the new `Order` object you've created as if it's an `Order` which already exists - that's why the `OrderID` in the error is zero.

Try this:

```
try
{
    //// Update
    var existingOrder = se.Orders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OrderNumber == orderNo);

    if (existingOrder != default(Order))
    {
        existingOrder.DateLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        se.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(existingOrder, EntityState.Modified);
    }
    //// Create
    else
    {
        se.Orders.AddObject(order);
    }
    se.SaveChanges();
}
```

*Edit*

You can update the order details property-by-property, or if you have an `Order` (or an `OrderViewModel`, perhaps) with the details you want to update, you could use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to copy the values for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm no longer getting the error, but I'm still unable to update. Can you give an example for `// Update existingOrder in some way...` (say, change the OrderNumber to something else)? I've tried `existingOrder = order;` but that didn't work. However, something like `existingOrder.OrderNumber = "543-88";` worked. Is there an easier way so I don't have to go through each field if I'm working with not just OrderNumber?

Comment: Thanks again! While there aren't a lot of properties in the object at the moment, I might just go with the Automapper route just in case requirements change in the future.